# SQL update all records except the last one with a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query where only the last line of each user that has a car gets a license plate number.

```
ID    UserId    LicensePlate    HasCar
1     1         ABC123          1
2     1         ABC123          1
3     2         NULL            0
4     3         UVW789          1
5     3         UVW789          1
```

Should become:

```
ID    UserId    LicensePlate    HasCar
1     1         NULL            1
2     1         ABC123          1
3     2         NULL            0
4     3         NULL            1
5     3         UVW789          1
```

So I basically need to find all users with a licenseplate and change all but the last one and make the LicensePlate `NULL`

Comment: Are these ordered on the `ID` field?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the ID column is an identity column so it can provide the ordering, something like this should do the trick:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, 
           UserId, 
           LicensePlate, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id DESC) rn
    FROM Table
    WHERE HasCar = 1
)

UPDATE CTE
SET LicensePlate = NULL
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: Fastest reply that worked for me without too much issues. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UPDATE l
SET l.LicensePlate = null
FROM Car l
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserId, Max(Id) AS max_id
            FROM Car 
            GROUP BY UserId) m ON m.UserId = l.UserId
                                  AND m.max_id <> l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a join on the table itself like that :

```
UPDATE car c
INNER JOIN car c2 ON c.userId = c2.userId AND c.id < c2.id AND c.HasCar = 1 AND c2.HasCar = 1
SET c.LicensePlate = NULL
```

The condition `c.id < c2.id` will avoid to select the last line

Answer (score 0):

By using LAG Function also you can achieve it.

```
  ;WITH License(ID,UserId,LicensePlate,HasCar)
as
(
SELECT 1,1,'ABC123',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'ABC123',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,NULL   ,0  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,3,'UVW789',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,3,'UVW789',1
)

SELECT ID,UserId,LAG(LicensePlate,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY LicensePlate),HasCar FROM License
```